# Is it worth studying econometrics? What added value does it have?

Tags: r, econometrics

I am currently at high school. I like math a lot so I am thinking about studying statistics or econometrics later at university. I also play around with R statistical software. I do not want to disrespect the subject or anyone. I am a bit confused by the subject, you will see later on. I was wondering what added value econometrics actually has. Is it really worth all the effort acquiring and studying it?

From what I actually know about it (from layperson perspective), it requires serious knowledge of maths, probability statistics and econometrics. For this reason one would say, that after acquiring such amount of knowledge one can do stuff. But I would like to know what kind of work I could actually do. Not just for the sake of research or academia itself. What are the real life applications? Who would pay me to perform econometric analysis for him? My first guess would be - time series - financial markets - predictions. But then there is efficient market hypothesis, one cannot predict the stock market. So I am asking what are other applications of econometrics that could pay you well and compensate for all the hard work.
Moreover, analysis of time series (for example for the purposes of finding proper trading strategy) requires tweaking and finding out what the results would be under different settings of variables. For that reason I expect one should possess serious computational power which is for financial reasons out of reach of regular folks. So my second question would be, is there any cloud computing CPU service which would allow me to run R code (thanks to doparallel) on multiple cores for some charge?

Comment: At your stage of education you should first get a very wide view of various mathematical disciplines, it is really to early for you to think much about specialization!

Comment: Any IaaS cloud platform should allow you to install and run R. But unless you're doing some big data stuff, it isn't really necessary for most applications.

Comment: Do you want to be an econometrician? -- There's an entire field (in the US at least) of economists who perform litigation support for antitrust and anticompetitive behavior. They're paid well. Moreover, the existence of antitrust as a field of litigation would appear to cast doubt on the efficient market hypothesis as some sort of universal truth. Amazon AWS is the go-to resource for cloud computing resources.

Comment: You can have a bright career in econometrics, but if you aren't interested in that specific field you can get a lot of the same skills out of a decision science course or elective statistics course. Even if you aren't interested in the specific applications that will come up, the skills you develop in an econometrics class can be generalized to a lot of fields, especially if you understand the underlying math well.

Answer (score 5):

Econometrics is an intensely mathematically rigorous discipline. Statistical computing skills alone do not point to a successful career as an econometrician, but they are probably useful for various types of Bayesian analyses, microsimulation models, and so on. At your stage of development, I would not be concerned about statistical computing but would rather focus on exposing myself to all forms of mathematical statistics, especially measure theory, probability, and classical inference.

Econometrics is of great value in the government and private sectors. Some types of work they do include forecasting costs/revenues, risk assessment, policy evaluation, and so on. You can have hard money positions within organizations like Vanguard or government, or you can have soft money positions in academics, or consulting.

Whether it's "worth the effort" is subjective. You should be proactive and setup phone interviews or shadow other econometricians in your city to see if it's right for you.

Comment: This is a great answer, but I wanted to add that there is an opportunity cost component to the "worth it" question. If the OP majors in economics, then econometrics will probably be required whether the OP uses it in a career or not. If majoring in statistics instead, econometrics might be an interesting course (and look good on a CV), but may not be preferable to another course.

Comment: @Upper_Case If OP's goal is to go on to study econometrics at the graduate level, OP's best likelihood for success is to major in statistics or mathematics. Having a basic sequence of economics is the easy part, whereas exposure to mathematical probability and statistics, linear algebra, differential equations is a *minimum* and ideally a student has exposure to measure theoretic real analysis, applied statistical analysis, and so on. On the other hand, an "econometrics for economists" course will probably be a gross simplification and no benefit to advanced study.

Comment: Tech is [another option](http://www.nytimes.com/2016/09/04/technology/goodbye-ivory-tower-hello-silicon-valley-candy-store.html), though I think the skills required to be very successful would be arguably broader that just econometrics. My advice would be to take lots of math, economics, econometrics, stats, and CS classes, and figure what you like.